# why glassfish 4.1 runs in netbeans 8.0 but in eclipse luna does not

Tags: java, ide, glassfish-4

I´m trying to work with eclipse and export my web apps made in netbeans, i just add a new server, download glassfish tools, and shows me an error:

```
Unable to start server due following issues:
```

Launch process failed with exit code 1

> Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
>   ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Acceso denegado))
>   java.lang.Exception: Unable to create bundle cache lock file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish-4.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix\cache.lock (Acceso denegado)

any help?

Comment: Have you full rights on the folder?

Comment: yes!!, even run eclipse as admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is a problem with the access rights.

If the file `cache.lock` is in the folder which is mentioned in the error message, you should check if it is in use by another process.

Even if you start Eclipse as Administrator, it may not start Glassfish as Administrator.

To fix the problem, you can move your Glassfish installation to a folder where you have write access without the Adminstrator account. Update the location of the Glassfish installation in Eclipse. This should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if cache.lock is being used/if it currently exists.

Check if glassfish is currently running.